# Can I sync my Dropbox camera uploads without using a wireless network?

Tags: dropbox, cloud

I'm currently travelling and taking a lot of photos on my smart phone.

I typically use Dropbox with the camera upload feature, to have them sync automatically to computer. At home this works perfectly, I take a photo with the camera and when I'm home it's immediately on my computer.

However, when I'm travelling I usually don't have access to reliable WiFi and I'm taking a lot more photos.  As a result I have hundreds of photos that are on my phone that aren't on my laptop.

Is there a way I can quickly sync them? eg. using a USB cable.

Comment: Why not just plug your phone into the laptop via USB and copy the pictures over?

Comment: If you are interested in backing up your photos, you have to find some alternative method to do so, as Dropbox needs a wireless network to work. It's just the nature of the way cloud storage services such as Dropbox work.

Answer (score 0):

As per the instruction from **Drop Box** on [**How do I use Camera Upload?**](https://www.dropbox.com/help/289)

You can take advantage of Camera Upload in two ways:

- Upload **wirelessly** from your phone or tablet using the iOS, Android,
  Windows Phone or Windows tablet app.
- Upload by **connecting** your camera, phone, or tablet to your computer
  and using the Mac or Windows desktop app.